# Starting a transaction from an external application running outside of API context is not allowed

Tags: revit, revit-api, revitpythonshell

Starting a transaction from an external application running outside of API context is not allowed.
cannot start transaction.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here... please elaborate.

Answer (score 10):

Using my magic psychic crystal ball to guess you are asking how to avoid getting this error message in your Revit / RPS plugins, here is a short bit of extra information:

- all Revit API calls should happen inside the "API context"
- this "API context" lives in a special thread
- you are probably accessing the API from another thread
- this often happens when you make a `Form`and call into the API from one of the events (`Button.OnClick`)

What you want to do is figure out how to get back into the API context to execute your code. There are two main methods for doing this (assuming you have already left the `IExternalCommand.Execute` context):

- polling for jobs inside the `Idling` event
- using an `ExternalEvent`

Since you mentioned RevitPythonShell in the tags, why don't you check out how I used [external events in my web server example](http://darenatwork.blogspot.ch/2015/06/embedding-webserver-in-autodesk-revit_30.html).

- create an `IExternalEventHandler`
- implement its `Execute` method
- (the `Execute` method runs in the Revit API context)
- create an `ExternalEvent` (using the event handler just created)
- when you need to do something in the Revit API context, notify the external event (`my_external_event.Raise()`)

Comment: > this "API context" lives in a special thread:
It's the UI thread, nothing special here.
> this often happens when you make a Form:
A modeless form, because a modal one cannot exit the API context

Comment: In addition, and for more details, The Building Coder provides an entire topic group on this subject:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.28