# How to call revit API from external thread?

Tags: exception, button, transactions, ribbon

I'am in the revit's test project,
When i create transaction , since evenement  '*ComponentManager_UIElementActivated*' from button of *ComponentManager.Ribbon*,
i have exception 'Starting a transaction from an external application running outside of API context is not allowed'.

Have you a solution ?

```
void ComponentManager_UIElementActivated(
      object sender,<br>
      adWin.UIElementActivatedEventArgs e)
{
Transaction trans = new Transaction(uidoc.Document); //Work good.<br>
trans.Start("ReTraceWall"); //It don't work, because i have  exception "Starting a transaction from an external application running outside of API context is not allowed."<br>
CommandRetraceWall.retracewall(uidoc); //function not called because there is exception before<br>
  trans.Commit();<br>
}
```

*

Thank  you for help .
Have you sample which solve this problem ?
[Sample using ComponentManager.Ribbon](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/pimp-my-autocad-or-revit-ribbon.html)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what Revit version you are using but there is a similar question to yours described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490990/starting-a-transaction-from-an-external-application-running-outside-of-api-conte). You have basically 2 options:

- polling for jobs inside the Idling event
- using an ExternalEvent

I won't elaborate it again here.

By the way, before asking a questions make a quick search in the forums as yours may already have an answer :)

Jeremy Tammik is a Revit API guru, he has an [entire blog](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/) that you may find useful as well.